# To select a common record when adding other field

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
A   |  B
1-1   10
1-1   10
1-1   12 
1-1   22
1-4   20
1-4   20
1-4   10
```

Output Table:

```
A  |  B
1    104
```

I have given the table and the output table. I am not able to generate that output. The output I get is given below and the code I used as well.

```
A   | B
1     54
1     50
```

The code I used is : `select  left(A,2) as A, SUm(KSL05) as B  from LKP_FAGLFLEXT where condition group by A`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use group by as below:

```
select left(a,2), sum(b) from yourtable
    group by left(a,2)
```

Comment: When I do that it says, that column is not contained in the group by clause.

Comment: @Rahul: This answer is correct. You want one result row per `left(a,2)`, so you group by it. (Or is it `left(a,1)`? Make sure the expression is the same in `GROUP BY` and `SELECT`.) Please re-check.

Comment: yep, I was doing left (1,a) which did give me 1 but did not sum. I have no idea how did that happen. But anyway stupid question actually :P Thanks tho!